# DataTable : Hide data as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide my data as default, and show the results `if` something in my Search Box.

[image]

Here is my current setting :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#inventory').dataTable({

      "lengthMenu": [ [5], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "search": {
        "caseInsensitive": true
      }
    });


    var dataTable = $('#inventory').dataTable();
    $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
      dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
    });  



  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you search some non-existent value (is there is any) just after creation of datatable like this.

```
$('#inventory').dataTable({

      "lengthMenu": [ [5], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "search": {
        "caseInsensitive": true
      }
    });


    var dataTable = $('#inventory').dataTable();      

dataTable.fnFilter('some non existant value');


    $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
      dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I can. I'm not sure if this is the best approach to do because I can still see my table, and the message said, `No matching records found` I am afraid that this will confuse my users, and leave.

Answer (score 0):

> First, wrap a `<div>` around my table and give it an id = `main`

```
<div id="main">

<table class="display" id="inventory">
    <thead class="thin-border-bottom ">

        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Stock</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>

        @foreach ( Inventory::all() as $inventory)

        <tr>

            <td>{{ $inventory->sku }} </td>
            <td>{{ $inventory->description }} </td>
            <td>{{ $inventory->stock }} </td>

        </tr>

        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>


</div>
```

> Second, fix my script to hide that div, and only show it when there is something in the search box.

```
$('#main').hide();


  // Setting to Inventory Table 
  $('#inventory').dataTable({

    "lengthMenu": [ 10 ] ,
    "bLengthChange": false,

  });


  // Bind the value from a new search to the dataTable
  var dataTable = $('#inventory').dataTable();

  $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
    dataTable.fnFilter(this.value);

    $('#main').show(); // show the main div 
  });
```